# Changing orientation of all text labels at once?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, labeling

I rotated my extent -45 degree to make it look better. Problem is all the labels that I converted to graphics so I could rearrange them are also at -45 degrees. Any way to change that easily?

[image]

Comment: Have you taken a look at this help page? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m70000005n000000

Comment: I changed annotation to labels in your title because they are different ways of rendering text and shapefiles do not support annotation.

Answer (score 2):

Select all the labels using the select elements tool. Right click one of the selected text elements.  Open the properties box.  In angles set the value to 45 (or -45).

Answer (score 2):

@CGB has provided a viable solution, however I'm not sure how the leaders on your labels would react (if at all) to the change in text orientation. If it doesn't come out looking nice, you could:

1. delete the existing label graphics
2. add a field of `integer` type to the labelled data, and calculate this to `45`
3. turn the labels back on
4. from the Label tab of the layer properties (or via the Labelling window), open the Placement Properties option and check the box next to `Rotate by attribute`
5. click the options button, select the new field as the rotation field
6. close all the windows and check the results